# SkyDrive desktop app with Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, onedrive

Is it possible to have the SkyDrive desktop app in Windows 8.1? I see it has a SkyDrive icon already installed in Metro tiles, but it wants me to hook up Windows 8 with an account. I really have no huge use of hooking up, and I would rather just have a local Windows 8 account.

Comment: The Skydive desktop application does not run on Windows 8.1 Skydrive is now built into Windows and requires you to link your local account to a Microsoft account

Comment: @Ramhound - hmm that sucks did you still get a desktop drive icon?

Comment: No, You do not.

Comment: So it is not accessible at all in desktop mode?

Comment: All functionality is baked into Windows.

Answer (score 0):

No, I am afraid it is not possible.

The quote below is from Microsoft's [official website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/windows-app-faq):

> OneDrive desktop app functionality is built into Windows 8.1. **If you
>   install the desktop app on a PC running Windows 8.1, Setup won't
>   appear. A setting will be installed that lets you use Office to work
>   on OneDrive documents with other people at the same time, but no other
>   features will be installed.** For help with OneDrive in Windows 8.1 and
>   Windows RT 8.1, see OneDrive: FAQ.

I researched this some time ago and ended up leaving using Skydrive and began using Dropbox instead, for the same reason you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

solved using networked drive ...
if you have Office 2013 then you can add one drive account then there you will get address add same address and create networked drive.