# Onedrive/Skydrive standalone app on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, onedrive

I have the following setup:

Windows 8.1 on PC at Work.
I use a local account.

My personal/private hotmail address, with all my personal data in Skydrive.

In Windows 8, I used to be able to have the Skydrive/Onedrive desktop app running, and connect it to my personal hotmail address. I could access, edit and sync my skydrive files at work: great!

Now upgraded to 8.1, it seems it is no longer possible?
I installed the desktop app, but it cannot be opened?

As said here, it is all baked in: [SkyDrive desktop app with Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/676570/skydrive-desktop-app-with-windows-8-1)

Now, this is very annoying, obviously: I can no longer access my files!

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: @Bertvan - You are indeed correct.  You are required to connect your Microsoft Account to your local account if you want this capability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Windows 8.1, signing in with a Microsoft account is required to let OneDrive sync your files. Short of relying on third party applications, you won't be able to have a setup similar to what you previously had in Windows 8.

The OneDrive/Microsoft account is now equivalent to iCloud/Apple: if you want to use iCloud to store your documents and access them across devices, you are forced to use the same iCloud account.

As an alternative, you might switch to a different cloud storage provider such as DropBox, Box, or Google Drive.

Comment: Indeed. That's actually pretty sad. Switching to Google Drive now.

Comment: @reploo - Actually....You are **NOT** forced to use a Microsoft Account to log into your account in Windows 8.1. It is required if you want to sync to OneDrive though. Please work on the wording of your first sentence.

Comment: @Ramhound I ask you to read again my answer. You can't use OneDrive in Windows 8.1 unless you login with a Microsoft Account. My sentence is actually stating exactly that - that you are forced to use a Microsoft Account in order to use OneDrive.

Comment: @reploo - I read your first sentence an entirely different way hence my comment.  I had to read it multiple times to read it the way you attempted to write it.

Comment: @reploo yet here I sit logged on with my corporate account, and all my skydrive files are sync'd just fine. A quick search showed me this: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/connect-microsoft-domain-account

Comment: Does anyone know how to remove credentials from the OneDrive app once they have been cached?

Comment: http://syncdriver.com/ is a great client that allows you to use OneDrive without signing into the PC under a Microsoft account.